# Google Cloud: Recovering Suspended VM Instance

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, cloudflare

My GCP server was suspended last week due to suspected cryptocurrency activity (which I did not partake in). After appealing and having my VM reinstated, my website no longer works (it is a wordpress site with a cloudflare domain).

My suspicion is that when the instance was suspended, the data on the disk was deleted. Would anyone have ideas as to how I could possibly recover the data on my site? I unfortunately did not have a backup and lessons learned!

Thank you!

I have not been able to contact neither Cloudflare nor GCP support, as they are for paid accounts only. From what I am seeing, I have not yet been able to find an FTP or SQL backup.